# discord.js send message foreach channel problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

````
client.on('message',async message => {
  let args = message.content.split(' ');
  if(args[0].toLowerCase() == `${prefix}mta`) {
  Gamedig.query({type: 'csgo',host: '185.198.75.5'}).then((state) => {
  var players = state.players.map(player => player.name)
  var playerss = state.players.map(x => x.score)
  console.log(state);
  message.channel.send(('```'+  players.join("\n-------------------------\n")+ playerss.join("\n-------------------------\n")+ '```'));
  })
  }
  })
````

Hello guys, I did the code I wanted at the end, but I couldn't set the articles as I wanted. I'm trying forEach, but I couldn't do it properly.

This is the output of the message

```
⌜Boom⌟ Best of Milk
-------------------------
BLACKJACKH35
-------------------------
Supreme  185.198.75.5
-------------------------
REDUX
-------------------------
NaberrMoruqq ama Yalnız olan
-------------------------
0
-------------------------
0
-------------------------
48
-------------------------
25
-------------------------
41
-------------------------
```

what I'm trying to do.

```
⌜Boom⌟ Best of Milk
Score: 0
-------------------------
BLACKJACKH35
Score: 0
-------------------------
Supreme  185.198.75.5
Score: 48
-------------------------
REDUX
Score: 25
-------------------------
NaberrMoruqq ama Yalnız olan
Score: 41
-------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating two variables and using two `map()` functions, you should just put it all in one.

````js
var players = state.players.map(
  (player) => `${player.name}\n${player.score}`
);

message.channel.send('```'+  players.join("\n-------------------------\n") + '```');
````